# Python3_imagemagick_convert_jpeg unsupported

Tags: python, imagemagick-convert

when I run the code below, it reports:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "ocr2.py", line 20, in <module>
>   image_jpeg = image_pdf.convert('jpeg')
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 3032, in convert
>  cloned.format = format
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 2932, in format
>  raise ValueError(repr(fmt) + ' is unsupported format')
> ValueError: 'jpeg' is unsupported format
> ```

Can anyone help me to figure out this problem? I dont understand why it says 'jpeg'is unsupported format.

```
from wand.image import Image
from PIL import Image as PI
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
import io

tool = pyocr.get_available_tools()[0]
lang = tool.get_available_languages()[1]
req_image = []
final_text = []

image_pdf = Image(filename="./test.pdf", resolution=300)
image_jpeg = image_pdf.convert('jpeg')

for img in image_jpeg.sequence:
    img_page = Image(image=img)
    req_image.append(img_page.make_blob('jpeg'))

for img in req_image:
    txt = tool.image_to_string(
        PI.open(io.BytesIO(img)),
        lang=lang,
        builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
    )
    final_text.append(txt)
```

Comment: Looking under the [list of supported formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported), there is a note saying that JPEG requires additional dependencies.

Comment: @J.Wen did you find the answer, I am also facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `image_pdf.convert('JPEG')`.

> [ImageMagick Image Formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php)
>       ImageMagick uses an ASCII string known as magick (e.g. GIF) to identify file formats